# Comparing a string value of 00 to an int value of 0 not 1

Tags: c++

I have a character array `charArray` with values `00`. `atoi(charArray)` yields 1 not 0. I want to transform 00 into just 0.

Comment: It shouldn't; can you show some code?

Comment: Yes give me a moment to update.

Comment: *"atoi(charArray) yields 1 not 0"* - This shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Not on GCC. http://ideone.com/XOsRyS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works fine. http://ideone.com/dpTMQq

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main( void ) {
    char charArray[] = "00";
    int intValue = atoi( charArray );
    assert( intValue == 0 );
}
```